# Excel to DataTable? Without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, excel, epplus

We do not have Microsoft Office installed on our machine. 
I am trying to read a excel file and store it in a Dataset  but I am getting error at

```
 Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
                        Dim Obj As Object

                        ws = DirectCast(workbook.Worksheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) <---error here
```

ERROR:      `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.`

I know its most probably there is no microsoft office installed on the machine. But is there an alternative? I tried Epplus but most of the code on internet about Epplus are in C# which I am not able to convert into vb using developer fusion or telerik.

Can some one please provide a simple snippet or something to get excel data into a DataSet? Thank you.

Comment: Epplus is a good option for Excel 2007+.  I suggest you don't give up because of your problems converting to VB.NET.  Try converting and post questions here about any problems you encounter, you'll soon pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a try [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) and [MYXLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/myxls/).

> Edit:Add some sample code for NPOI.

```
public static DataTable ExcelInput(string FilePath) 
    {            
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        //Get the excel from filepath
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open));
        HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)workbook.GetSheetAt(0);   

        //get Excel rows
        int rowsCount = sheet.PhysicalNumberOfRows;           

        int colsCount = sheet.GetRow(0).PhysicalNumberOfCells;

        for (int i = 0; i < colsCount; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < rowsCount; x++)
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            for (int y = 0; y < colsCount; y++)
            {
                dr[y] = sheet.GetRow(x).GetCell(y).ToString();
            }
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        sheet = null;
        workbook = null;
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Can please provide some code too? I have no idea how to use it with VB

Answer (score 0):

For sure you get an error when calling Excel interop with no excel installed!

But to get you started: [Creating an Excel Workbook with VB.NET and ASP.NET](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Creating-an-Excel-Workbook-3d4a7776)